# Including a full thread in the body of a reply from a bot

Tags: botframework

I created a bot that replies to mails. I use the Message.CreateReplyMessage(...) method.
The created message will contain the "Re: " prefix in it's subject but the body will not contain the previous messages on the thread, or at least the message sent to the bot.

Is there a way to have the body include the previous messages so it would look more like when we reply from outlook?

Thanks,

Uri

Answer (score 0):

You have the full text of the message in the call to your bot.  You can just append it to the end of your reply

Comment: When replying to a mail in outlook, the text from the previous mail will also have a header with the from/to/subject and all that. Just concatenating the previous body will not add that header. I wanted to know if there is a way to avoid having to construct the entire header myself.